# how we can mock and setup this GetCache

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

In actual data access layer method

```
var cache = _cacheProvider.GetCache<IDictionary<Guid, DataExportRequestModel>>(CacheName.Redis.ToString(),
            new TimeSpan(_cacheTTLDays, 0, 0, 0)); // Timespan of two days
```

In Setup Method.

```
_mockRediscacheProvider = new Mock<IRedisCacheProvider>();
```

In Test Method

```
_mockRediscacheProvider.Setup(x=>x.GetCache(CacheName.Redis.ToString(), new TimeSpan(_cacheTTLDays, 0, 0, 0)));
```

I am trying to fix this compilation error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [CS0411](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0411?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0411)) compiler error you're getting, it is failing because the compiler can't infer the type arguments of your `GetCache` method.

So update your mock `GetCache` setup call with your desired type arguments. For example:

```cs
_mockRediscacheProvider
 .Setup(x=>x.GetCache<IDictionary<Guid,DataExportRequestModel>>(...);
```